# CPU Frequency Scaling BASH Script

Tags: linux, bash, cpu

I've written a script to run when my PC starts up and it's supposed to overwrite "energy_performance_preference" and "scaling_governor" with ones that have different values.

What's happening is only the first command is being run for some reason. I have a similar script for something else that uses the same process of opening konsole and running multiple commands in succession as root.

Here's my script so far [CPU_Boost](https://pastebin.com/v9xXFgVA).

See [CPU frequency scaling](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling) for more information.

Comment: How did you conclude that only the first command is ran? Why did you mention the other script? What is their relation to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only the first command is being run for some reason

This is because you have the following:

```
konsole -e sudo cp -f /home/austin/CPU_Boost/energy_performance_preference /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/; cp -f /home/austin/CPU_Boost/scaling_governor /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/; chown root:root /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference; chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference; [...]
```

Bash will split commands by a semicolon (not newline), so what is being run is more like below (shown with one command per line):

```
konsole -e sudo cp -f /home/austin/CPU_Boost/energy_performance_preference /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/
cp -f /home/austin/CPU_Boost/scaling_governor /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/
chown root:root /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference
chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/energy_performance_preference
[...]
```

You're also lucky that `konsole` "*will catch all following arguments passed to Konsole*" <sub>[[ref](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/applications/konsole/command-line-options.html)]</sub> - most commands will not do this, instead taking `sudo` as the parameter to the `-e` and trying to handle `cp`, `-f`, `/home/austin/...` as other command line arguments.

---

`cp` isn't really appropriate for use with writing to `sysfs`... even if it works. You would be more likely to have success with redirection, or `tee`.

For example, if your `scaling_governor` file contains the text `performance`, then you could do the following:

```
echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy0/scaling_governor
```

Then there would be no need for the subsequent `chown` or `chmod`. That's three commands down to one.

---

You're doing that once for each of `policy0`, `policy1`, `policy2` and `policy3`. How about the following:

```
sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor <<<"performance"
```

That's four repetitions down to one call to `tee` - and it'll even automatically adjust for different systems (my system has 8 policies, not 4).

Repeat that again for `energy_performance_preference` and the value you'd like to use.

---

As for getting it to show up in `konsole`... do you need it to? Can't you just run it as a bash script?

Perhaps if you really want, you could use the following as a command / shortcut to launch the script:

```
konsole -e "${PATH_TO_SCRIPT}"
```

Comment: Code golfing: `tee` accepts several outputs, so you don't need to loop, you can just do: `echo "performance" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_governor`.

Comment: Then the "**Repeat that loop again**" later no longer makes sense, since there is no loop :)